# double integration using rectangular method in C

Tags: c, math

i would like to know how can i calculate the double integral shown in the picture below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUoOM.png]

i need to calculate it in C using the rectangular method
i already know how to calculate an integral but not a double one
i have calculated the above integral like this in C
integral(1/(1+x^2)) x from 0 to 1
but i do not understand how i should proceed any further

if someone can point me to the right direction on how i should approach this solution.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Do you not understand double integrals?

Comment: yeah, consult an introductory calculus book. (hint: you may find nested loops useful.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about maths.

Comment: This is an easy integration to perform using Gaussian quadrature.  The rectangular domain couldn't be simpler, and the function is well behaved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the definition of the (cascading) [*Riemann integral*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral):

```
int n = 5000;//or a large number, the discretization step
double dxy = 1.0d/n;
double integral = 0.0d;
for(int yi = 0; yi < n; yi++) {
    double y = yi*dxy; //the y-value
    for(int xi = 0; xi < n; xi++) {
        double x = xi*dxy; //the x-value
        integral += 1.0d/(1.0d+x*x+y*y); //function call
    }
}
return integral*dxy*dxy;
```

In other words, you calculate the integral like:

[image]

Comment: The name of the man was "Riemann" (just to find it on wikipedia).

Answer (score 0):

This double integral is effectively calculating the volume from the plane z = 0 to the surface defined by z = 1 / (1 + x^2 + y^2) for y = 0 to 1, x = 0 to 1. The following example calculates the volume of (n^2) columns with height z and square base Δy Δx using the mid point of the square bases to calculate z. Other than using the mid point of the squares, it's the same as CommuSoft's example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define n 1000
/* sum should ~= 0.63951 */
int main()
{
int ix, iy;
double x, y, sum, dydx;
    dydx = 1./((double)n * (double)n);
    sum = 0.0;
    for(iy = 0; iy < n; iy++){
        y = (0.5+(double)iy)/((double)n);
        for(ix = 0; ix < n; ix++){
            x = (0.5+(double)ix)/((double)n);
            sum += 1. / (1. + x*x + y*y);
        }
    }
    sum *= dydx;
    printf("%.15lf\n", sum);
    return(0);
}
```